# static compilation and got, plt sections.

Tags: c, linux, gcc, compiler-construction, linker

I am writing a toy elf loader for some small project. To test my loader, I have been compiling my app statically. However, I realized even after static compilation, my app still contains .got and .got.plt sections.

I read that now a days complete static compilation has been removed from linux. Is there any way to use standard libc and compile an application statically? or Do I need to use some other libc like uClibc?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps look at http://musl-libc.org/

Comment: What architecture are you targeting?

Comment: I am writing a user space elf loader on x86-64.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Do you if there is any way to use standard libc in static manner? I can use musl-libc. But I more looking for a solution to use standard libc. And do you why designed went away from static approach?

Comment: If I compile with `gcc -static main.c -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now`, I get rid of .got.plt (but I still have .got and .plt).